# Fitting Data to an Unknown Distribution

Tags: bayesian, optimization, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting

Consider a sample $x_1,\ldots,x_n \sim F$ from an unknown parametric distribution where $F$ is the cumulative distribution. We observe data in the form $F(x_1),\ldots,F(x_n)$. Stated differently, we observe some points on the unknown cumulative distribution function. We are interested in finding the best fitting parametric distribution.

If we assume a functional form for $F$, say a normal distribution $\Phi$, such that $F(x_j) = \Phi(x_j|\theta) + \epsilon_j,\ \epsilon_j \overset{\text{iid}} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,s^2)$, then one can find $\theta = (\mu, \sigma^2)$ by minimizing the sum of squared distance between the observed values and a normal cdf evaluated at values $x_1,\ldots,x_n$

$$
\underset{\theta} \min \sum_{j=1}^n (F(x_j) - \Phi(x_j|\theta))^2
$$

This looks similar to a non-linear least squares problem. However, since the data is sequential, I do not want to optimize again when I get a new observation. Instead, I would like to update the parameters of my normal distribution using a simple update. Is it possible to setup a prior on $\theta$ and get a posterior $p(\theta|x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, then I can use the posterior to get a posterior predictive distribution values for unobserved $x_{n+1}$ 
$$
\Phi(x_{n+1}|x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\int_{\Theta} \Phi(x_{n+1}|\theta)p(\theta|x_1,\ldots,x_n)d\theta
$$

Comment: Let $y_i = F(x_i|\theta)$. Do you observe $x_{1:n} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ or $y_{1:n} = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ or both?

Comment: Because $x_j$ appears alone in the minimization formula, evidently you have observed ordered pairs $(x_j, F(x_j\mid\theta)).$ In most circumstances, wouldn't that let you solve *exactly* for $\theta$ after making $n$ independent observations where $n$ is the dimension of $\theta$? *E.g.*, in your Normal distribution example, $n=2$ ought to suffice.  What's the point of solving the minimization problem--or indeed of obtaining any more than $n$ observations?

Comment: @mef I observe both

Comment: @whuber If $x_i$ are unique then you point is well taken, I can solve a system for both $(\mu, \sigma)$ with just two observations. However, $x_i$ may be repeated and corresponding $y$ values may be different.

Comment: If you are sampling from continuous distributions, then the chance of a repetition is zero.  Your formulation is very strange: could you edit your post to explain what you're doing in non-mathematical terms?  In particular, could you explain exactly how you observe the values of a CDF and why there are no errors in any of your observations?

Comment: Then $y_i = F(x_i|\theta) + \varepsilon_i$ where (for example) $\varepsilon_i \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} \textsf{N}(0,s^2)$.

Comment: @mef. $F(x_i) = \Phi(x_i|\theta) + \epsilon_i$ where for example $\epsilon_i \overset{\text{iid}}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,s^2)$ and $\Phi$ is known and $\theta$ must be estimated

Comment: @RohitArora maybe take a look at the kalman filter?

Comment: Note that the values in the ECDF are not independent, nor do they have constant variance. Why would you not use MLE instead?

Comment: @glen_b the problem is not using MLE or least squares. The problem is avoiding to do it everytime there is a new point. I just want to fit the best cdf through observed cdf data. It does not matter whether it is a parametric function or a non-parametric function and I want to use the fact that information arrives sequentially.